# What does the regular expression "\d{1,6}" check for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

What does the regular expression "\d{1,6}" (used in an ASP.NET MVC route as parameter constraint) check for/allow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That will match 1-6 consecutive occurrences of any of the digits 0-9 (not necessarily the *same* digit).

Comment: acc. even though later because you clarified that it has to be consecutive.

Answer (score 4):

a number with 1-6 digits

Comment: "100,000" is a number with 6 digits.

Comment: So is 1.623e-12 but that's *also* being picky :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be picky, but regular expressions are very picky about what they will match. :)

Comment: No, you *should* be picky. Engineering is, after all, meant to be an exact science. Otherwise I would have majored in English Lit.

Answer (score 4):

\d is the class for digits
the {1,6} means one to six element(s) of that class

if you want some reference you can consult this [website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) probably not the best but kind of nice summary.

Answer (score 1):

\d means **a single** decimal character. 0~9.

{minimum-length, maximum-length} means a precede expression (\d in this case) will be followed  repeatedly.

As a result, your expression \d{1,6} would match any of them.

0
12
874
4757
48727
557473